# need some help on server-client socket comunication

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to do an exercise on the sockets in java and make a client communicate with a server, I can't understand why the server gets stuck on the read and it's as if it didn't receive messages from the client, when in reality the client sends them.
the client is viewed correctly by the server and the accept is successful. how to do it?

Server code

```
ServerSocket server = null;
Socket client = null;
while(true) {
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket();
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 2000));
        client = server.accept();
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

BufferedReader reader = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    String message = null;
    while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Client send: " + message);
        String answer = "ok"; 
        writer.write(answer);
        writer.flush();

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Client code

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
try {
    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",2000);
    socket.connect(address);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader reader = null;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {       
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    String string = "hello";
    writer.write(string);
    writer.flush();
    System.out.print("sent");
    String message;
    while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Server send: " + message);
        break;
    }
}catch (SocketException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println(e);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When is this loop: `while(true) {
        Socket client = null;
        try{
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }` supposed to exit?

Comment: And ***how*** is it supposed to exit?

Comment: You look to need a break in there, something on the order of `client = server.accept(); break;`. Better still, create a ClientHandler that accepts the newly created server socket and run it in new thread for each client.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, just forgot to add break; when I copied the code to stackoverflow. However my problem is when the server does the message = reader.readLine(), it doesn't receive anything and it gets stuck even if the client does writer.write(string);

Comment: `"...sorry, just forgot to add break"` -- this is important information then that you're leaving out, diverting our ability to answer the question. Please let's avoid this. Consider posting [mre] code that we can test, real code that you yourself have tested.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have already added break; and I think I posted a minimal reproducible example, do you need something more?

Comment: Can I or anyone else copy and paste this code into an IDE, compile and run it? Please read the [mre] link and then reply back, especially if anything about the MRE construct is confusing or not clear.

Comment: Also, this `"localhot"` looks quite problematic. Please tell me that this is not present in your actual code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels localhost corrected, it is not present in my actual code, it's just some mistake in copying and pasting. Now you can copy and paste on your ide

Comment: Your comment suggests that you haven't yet read the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link. While creating one of this is not a requiement, it does help when asking about debugging issues since we can reproduce the issue and see it for ourselves. I hope that you get an answer soon, and that you don't need to create a MRE, but if you need my help, ***again*** please read the link. Please comment back to me only after you've read the link

Comment: No imports, no class declaration, no main method,... again, if anything in the MRE link confuses, please ask and I will gladly explain, but again please read the link.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your client's hard-code InetAddress corresponds correctly to the host's "localhost"?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes again, the client is recognized correctly during accept()

Comment: Do you see why a MRE is important now? It allows us to compile, run, test and modify your code, helping us to understand the problem and figure out a solution. Does this make sense? Since you are the one asking the question and we are volunteers, the onus of the effort to create one of these should be yours not ours.

Answer (score 0):

My MRE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> ServerFun.someServerMethod()).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        new Thread(() -> ClientFun.someClientMethod()).start();
    }
}
```

```
class ClientFun {
    public static void someClientMethod() {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("LocalHost", 2000);
            System.out.println("client socket address: " + address);
            socket.connect(address);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String string = "hello";
            writer.write(string);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
            System.out.print("sent");
            String message;
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server send: " + message);
                break;
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ServerFun {
    public static void someServerMethod() {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client = null;
        // !!while (true) {  // not needed for a single client
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket();
                server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 2000));
                System.out.println("server socket: " + server.getInetAddress());
                client = server.accept();
                // !! break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        // !! }
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            String message = null;
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Client send: " + message);
                String answer = "ok";
                writer.write(answer);
                writer.newLine();
                writer.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to send a new line for the `readLine` methods to work. e.g.,

```
writer.write(answer);
writer.newLine();  // add this **********
writer.flush();
```

This needs to be in place for both client and server. Alternatively, use a PrintWriter and `out.println(answer);`

I also had to use "localhost" for the client to work.

Hopefully, you see the utility of MRE in our solving this. Next time, I hope you will create one for us rather than forcing us to create one.